# What's wrong with the following proof of charaterization of tangent space for immersed submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $S\subset M$ be the smoothly embedded submanifold( with $dim(S) = k$ and $\dim(M) = n$).We have the following theorem:

> $T_{p} S=\left\{v \in T_{p} M: v f=0 \text { whenever } f \in C^{\infty}(M) \text { and }\left.f\right|_{S}=0\right\} \text { . }$

I want to change the proof a little bit,to see why the following proof does not apply to immersed submanifold.So we assume that $S\subset M$ is smooth immersion only.

**Step 1.**: First to show $vf = 0$ : $v f=d \iota_{p}(w) f=w(f \circ \iota)=0 .$ which needs not the embedding condition.

**Step 2.**:We need to show that $vf = 0$ implies there exist some $w\in T_pS$ such that $di_p(w) = v$.

To do this,we apply the rank theorem.which says exist some neiborhood $V\subset S$ and $U\subset M$ such that $V\subset U$.And the coordinate representation of $i:V\to M$ is $$i(x_1,...,x_k) = (x_1,...,x_k,0,...,0)$$

in these coordinates, it follows that $T_{p} S$ (that is, $d \iota_{p}\left(T_{p} S\right)$ ) is exactly the subspace of $T_{p} M$ spanned by $\partial /\left.\partial x^{1}\right|_{p}, \ldots, \partial /\left.\partial x^{k}\right|_{p}$. If we write the coordinate representation of $v$ as
$$
v=\left.\sum_{i=1}^{n} v^{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\right|_{p}
$$

we see that $v \in T_{p} S$ if and only if $v^{i}=0$ for $i>k$.

**Step 3.** :Let $\varphi$ be a smooth bump function supported in $U$ that is equal to 1 in a neighborhood of $p$. Choose an index $j>k$, and consider the function $f(x)=\varphi(x) x^{j}$, extended to be zero on $M \backslash \operatorname{supp} \varphi$. Then $f$ vanishes identically on $S$, so
$$
0=v f=\sum_{i=1}^{n} v^{i} \frac{\partial\left(\varphi(x) x^{j}\right)}{\partial x^{i}}(p)=v^{j}
$$
Thus $v \in T_{p} S$ as desired.

Which is almost the same as the proof provided on Lee's smooth manifold book prop 5.37. page 116

**Except for the fact that we use rank theorem instead of slice chart lemma.**

There must be something wrong with my proof,but I can't find it.

Comment: I suggest, you do not use the notion of an immersed manifold, but the notion of an immersion, $f: S\to M$ where $S, M$ are smooth manifolds. Then the right notion is that of $Df(T_pS)\subset T_{f(p)}M$.

Comment: thanks,but i can't figure out why is necessary to change it to immersion map,since I want to inverstigate the difference between $S\subset M$ as immersed submanifold and embedded submanifold?

Comment: For instance, tangent space for an immersed submanifold is ill-defined, local structure is quite horrible. I wish textbooks stopped using this notion which only leads to a confusion.

Comment: There exist some place that must use the notion of immersed submanifold,for instance the Lie subgroup only need the immersion condition.

Comment: Those are injectively immersed and even in this case it is better to consider a triple $f:S\to M$ instead of a subset.

Comment: Oh thanks I get the point.

Comment: As for a mistake in your proof, it is in the beginning of step 3 (imagine that $S$ is dense in $M$).

Comment: thank you ,I see :since in neighborhood  $U\subset M$,there may exist $V_1$ and $V_2$ are both part of $S$ and contains in $U\subset M$ although in $V$, $f$ identical vanish it does not means $f$ vanish on $V_2$.So $f$ constructed above needs not vanish on whole $S$.

Comment: Good question. I finally understand what you guys mean. A simple example where the proof invalid, such as here :https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BgtP.png will do the job.

Comment: @MoisheKohan This [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=immersed%20submanifold) gives 306 hits in math.stackexchange. Yes, we all should  wish that textbooks stop using this notion.

Comment: @PaulFrost Not surprisingly, this item is so popular on MSE, since the terminology is inconsistent, sloppy and confusing.